How to train GMM-HM to create an acoustic model in speech recognition
I want to understand how the GMM-HMM acoustic model is trained, which can output a sequence of phonemes from an input audio recording containing speech. If you look at the training datasets (for example, on Voxforge), then there is a set of audio recordings of phrases, and their transcription, without a specific binding of phonemes to time intervals. How does the same CMU Sphinx manage to understand where one phoneme begins and another ends in the training record?
I am haunted by the idea that transcription alignments need to be done manually. To get an acoustic model for each phoneme.
